What is missing from this vee-validate example in vue?
I'm trying to use yup and vee-validate with vue 3, but the validate function isn't working as I expect it to.
Here is a simple component I set up in my template
<PwInput :class="{'input-validation-error': isSubmitted && errors.name }"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            v-model="modalData.name"
            :label="$t('Name')">
</PwInput>

Here's how i've set up my data
<script setup lang="ts">
    import * as Yup from 'yup'
    import { useForm }  from 'vee-validate';
// Modal Data
const modalData = reactive<any>({
    name: '',
    isAnonymous: false
})
const isSubmitted = ref<boolean>(false)

// Validation
const schema = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().required('Name is required').min(4, 'too short'),
});
const { errors, validate } = useForm({
    validationSchema: schema,
});

and finally the method that is executed upon submission
const create = async (): Promise<void> => {
    isSubmitted.value = true;

    console.log(errors.value)
    console.log(modalData)

    const data = await validate()
    console.log(data)

    return;
}

The issue is that I can see that modalData.name is 'abcdef' and and the validation still fails and the error reason given is "name is required" suggesting that the modalData is not correctly bound to the validation. I have look through the docs and it seems I have set up everything correctly so I wonder if someone with a bit more experience has any insight

Got it working with defineField from vee-validate
const [name, nameProps] = defineField('name')

